# Writing a fortran file in columns

Tags: fortran

i'm trying to write a Fortran file with arrays of 2000 elements each, every 1000 program steps. At first, I tried to write it in the following way:

`if(i.eq.1000)
open (21,file='eedf.res',status='unknown',position='append')
   write(21,121) (eedf(le),le=1,2000)
close (21)
i=0`
.
.
.

(eedf is then put equal to zero and the array is rebuilt in the following 1000 steps; we are inside a do-loop).

It works,producing a file with the arrays printed on rows, but the program that i use to plot these functions tells me that there are too much columns, and so the last half of columns are lost...
So, I want to write eedf in columns, the first with eedf after the first 1000 program step, the second with eedf after the following 1000 program step, and so on. How can i do that?

eedf(1)       eedf(1)

eedf(2) eedf(2)

.

.

eedf(2000) eedf(2000)

Sorry if i've been verbose, i tried to put it in the clearest way.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A better strategy would be to accumulate the results into an array and then, at the end of the computation, write the array to file in the order you want.  Much easier than any nonsense jumping around the disk trying to write the file out of order.

Comment: Oh man, I'm so stupid. Thanks and sorry.